# Parse out a URL query argument in javascript

Tags: javascript, parsing, url, url-parsing

I'm using javascript and need to parse out a query argument that is a URL:

```
/folderone/two?link=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cooldomainname.com
```

This is doubly hard because I not only need to parse out the query argument "link", but once I have that, the "://" seems to have been turned into: "%3A%2F%2F"

I got so far as to do this:

```
url.replace(/^.*\=/, '');
```

Which left me with:

```
http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cooldomainname.com
```

But now I still need to handle these "%3A%2F%2F"  I could just do a find and replace, but I feel like there must be some type of library that I should be using to "de-URLify" query arguments?

Comment: please add a `javascript` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
decodeURIComponent("http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cooldomainname.com");
```

Output:

```
"http://www.cooldomainname.com"
```

Note also that I think `split` is a more natural choice than `replace`:

```
"/folderone/two?link=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cooldomainname.com".split("=")[1]
```

(It's assumed that your input string has just the one parameter.)